Dynamic node in ROS2 humble
I want to create a dynamic behaviour of the node. Consider a scenario, one node (pub_1_node) is publishing on one topic named "common_topic". Second node(sub_1_node) is subscribing to the same topic "common_topic"and callback is executed and publishes data on "result_topic". While this process in running, the third node(pub_2_node) also publishes on the "common_topic". Now I want to fuse the data from both nodes (pub_1_node & pub_2_node) at run time without stopping and restarting any node.  How can I change the behaviour of the subscriber node(sub_1_node) so that it also listen to the data from the second publisher as well.
Thank you for any suggestions in advance.
